# Bind click event to Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have Jquery latest connected and working with other parts of application.

**0.** End goal: for a modal window to appear on the screen.

**1.** I click on a button.

**2.** A function runs that append a modal to `body`

**3.** With modals, in order for this modal to actually show on the screen, I 
need to 
  press a button that has `data-target="#EnterModalNameHere"`

**4.** I make a hidden button in index.html that has the needed `data-target` 
property.

**5.** I would like to be able to click this hidden button once the function in step 
  **2** finishes appending the modal.

How can I tell Javascript "once finished appending modal, click on hidden button"?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you're trying to accomplish? It's already sounding like an XY problem.

Comment: "go the index.html" ? As in change pages or... ?

Comment: share some code, so we can see if you have already jquery or not

Comment: Is index.html the same document as the current document?

Comment: $(document).load( {--then call your function here  }) or 
<body onload="myFunc()">

Comment: Edited to make clearer. Thanks guys.

Comment: $("#hiddenButton").trigger("click");

Comment: you could just launch your modal with `$('#EnterModalNameHere').modal('show');` This is less complicated than programmatically clicking a button

Comment: Using $('#EnterModalNameHere').modal('show') works instead of trying to click a hidden button programmatically. Thanks I.R.R

Comment: In general, anytime you find you need to _trigger_ some UI event (outside of actual UI testing), you are probably going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can create an Event.

You can create a custom Event which would be dispatch (trigger) immediately after
the document is ready.
So, in your situation, since you aren't using a media query, you can use :

- SetTimeout like `setTimeout(() => { do something }, timeout);`. So, the timeout could be 1000 - which means 1sec and so on,
- A custom event which you can trigger when the modal successfully appended to the body.
- An Event Listeners Like load `window.onload = function() { enter code here }`

Comment: 1 -  so I can say something 'when a short milisecond set timeout is reacher do x'?